# Crawled currently not indexed sustain indexed pages decrease! What could be causing this?

Tags: seo

Crawled currently not indexed sustain indexed pages decrease! What could be causing this?

These pages are getting deindexed slowly. I lose a few hundred pages a week. These pages go from submitted and indexed to "Crawled currently not indexed".

When I inspect the, "Crawled currently not indexed" it shows up all green, has a referring page and says Index able but "URL will be indexed only if certain conditions are met". Nothing seems wrong with the pages. Not sure what to do to stop the deindexing. The site is ncservo.com if it helps.